# how to customize Dialog header in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, dialog

I'm using a custom dialog that I've created in a separate xml file in my project, and I'm coloring the main window a blueish tint, 
but the main header still remains the default white color.

Is there no way to change the font color, size, background for the header?

Is the only thing I can change in the header the text?

**xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:background="#3edfbc"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="Initlizing Wifi"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <com.github.ybq.android.spinkit.SpinKitView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/barcodeScanning_spinkit"
        style="@style/SpinKitView.Large.FoldingCube"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textaligmentManager_loader_textview"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        app:SpinKit_Color="#ffffff" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

**dialog:**

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.aligment_manager_loader_layout);
        dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        //set up text
        loaderScreenMainText = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.textaligmentManager_loader_textview);
        loaderScreenMainText.setText("Loading Wifi");


        //progressBar = (ProgressBar) dialog.findViewById(R.id.barcodeScanning_spinkit);
        //DoubleBounce doubleBounce = new DoubleBounce();
        //progressBar.setIndeterminateDrawable(doubleBounce);


        //now that the dialog is set up, it's time to show it
        dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Design your custom layout in such a way that the layout itself contains the header part. And then skip this code:

```
dialog.setTitle("Loading");
```

Instead add this statement:

```
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

You can also use AlertDialog. In that case requestWindowFeature() method is not required.

```
 android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);
 LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);
 View customView = inflater.inflate(your_layout, null);
 builder.setCancelable(false);
 loaderScreenMainText = (TextView) customView.findViewById(R.id.textaligmentManager_loader_textview);
 loaderScreenMainText.setText("Loading Wifi");
 builder.setView(customView);
 AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
 dialog.show();
```

Comment: it will still show a title area.. just without text... meaning it still shows a white area in the screen

Comment: Add this statement: dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Comment: you cannot do this at that stage, as ive already set content on the view on the create (it doesn't work ...)

Comment: Add the statement immediate after this statement: Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);  After that set your content.

Comment: i did, it still shows, android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content.

Comment: I am also saying to add the statement before adding content. The sequence is:
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.aligment_manager_loader_layout);
dialog.setCancelable(false);

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlertDialog which is a subclass of Dialog class. Here you can define a custom layout containing everything such as title, body and buttons. No extra title section will appear. Here is a demo:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(Scanning_Barcode_Activity.this);
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.aligment_manager_loader_layout, null);
    TextView loaderScreenMainText = (TextView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.textaligmentManager_loader_textview);
    loaderScreenMainText.setText("Loading Wifi");
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of stylish open source libraries that you can use for customizing header parts.

Here I'm sharing my newly developed open source library : [`PanterDialog`](https://github.com/kngfrhzs/panter-dialog)

Hope it will help you.